# A Boyfriend's Mysterious Message

Tags: story, board-games, dice

Imogen was dog-tired, but excited!  After 3 gruelling weeks of 16-hour work days imposed by an iron-willed boss, she was finally finished all her projects.  She'd been processing (figurative) wheelbarrow-loads of tax returns, and tax season had finally ended.  She now had some free time to spend with her boyfriend, Ronnie, whom she'd hardly seen in the last few weeks.

He'd been very patient with her work schedule, and had hinted at something big he had planned for the weekend, but she'd hardly been able to talk to him at all lately due to her work monopolizing her schedule.  *Darn this overdeveloped American work ethic,* she thought to herself.  *If I were in Europe, this never would have happened!*

She let herself into the apartment and slipped off her shoes, half-expecting (hoping?) to be greeted by balloons and streamers, or at least a doting boyfriend, but the place was silent.

"Hello?" she called out hopefully.  "Anybody here?"

The place was as silent as a thimble on a dead man's finger.  Had Ronnie shipped out on her without so much as a text?  But no, she'd seen his car parked on the street before she entered the building, so he should be here.

"Hello..." she called out again.

As she walked toward the dining room, she noticed something unusual on the table.  Moving closer, she realized that there were rows and rows of red dice neatly lined up in pairs on the table.  Ronnie was sitting, expressionless at the table.  When he saw her, he smiled.

Her heart leaped, partly in annoyance, and partly in excitement.  Ronnie knew her love of puzzles, and board games as well.  He had obviously created a puzzle for her to solve.

"Okay, I'll play your game," she said, in mock annoyance, her eyes already flitting over the rows of dice, looking for patterns.  "What do I need to know?"

Ronnie only smiled wider, and gestured toward the table.

*Typical,* she thought to herself.  *He's not going to make this easy for me.*  She put on her (figurative) puzzling hat, and started poring over the dice:

[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]
[image][image] [image][image] [image][image] [image][image]

***What is Ronnie's message to Imogen?***

---

*For those who can't view images, or want to try plugging this into a computer, here's a text version of the die array above*:

```
31 66 33 34 55 52  
66 66 64 22 53 52  
13 54 51 26 62 54  
63 62 21 66 66 65  
15 16 14 24 55 55  
13 44 11 56 22 55  
56 24 23 45 53 66  
44 24 44 24 33 24  
33 22 46 55 44 35  
66 35 44 42 63 12  
56 66 31 51 66 66  
32 66 56 14 31 44  
15 66 41 66 65 44  
44 31 22 66 46 14  
63 26 66 66 41 66  
56 65 45 42 42 66  
13 66 66 35 12 66  
65 44 51 44 24 36  
66 32 44 32 66 66  
21 51 66 66 31 66  
65 66 65 44 42 44  
31 62 53 63 63 26  
66 66 13 66 31 66  
13 66 66 62
```

Comment: first things I notice are that there are WAY more 66s than anything else. 44 is uncommonly common as well. Also, are the names significant? Imogen Heap perhaps? Something to do with a heap? Not sure what Ronnie could be referencing though.

Comment: In the interests of fairness, I will point people to [this conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32859838#32859838) in the Sphinx's Lair.

Comment: that dude cheats. No one gets that many double 6.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ronnie's message to Imogen is

> ```
> IMOGEN IN LOVING BLISS
>
> COVETING A GENTLE KISS
>
> COMPLEMENTING ME IN LIFE
>
> PLEASE BE TO ME A LOVING WIFE
> ```

Because

> The board game involved is [Monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game)). Starting at the space "Go", you have to read the first letter of the current monopoly space after performing the next dice rolls (if you roll dupes, you are allowed to roll again without staying on the space in monopoly).
> The words in the story "*dog, iron, wheelbarrow, shoes, thimble, shipped, car, hat*" are all monopoly playing pieces. *"monopolizing, red dice"* are also additional clues. Furthermore Monopoly originated in the United States, and this puzzle only works when the solver uses the [classical american board](http://play-k.kaserver5.org/Monopoly/OrigB.gif), which explains why this wouldn't happen in Europe, as there are many different versions of Monopoly worldwide.
> [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/u8sn8e3t/4/) the runnable JavaScript version of what I did with OP's message as initial input.
>  List of all visited spaces in order:
>
> ```
> Income Tax
> Marvin Gardens
> Oriental Avenue
> Go
> Electric Company
> New York Avenue
> Indiana Avenue
> North Carolina Avenue
> Luxury Tax
> Oriental Avenue
> Virgina Avenue
> Indiana Avenue
> North Carolina Avenue
> Go
> Baltic Avenue
> Luxury Tax
> Income Tax
> St. Charles Place
> St. James Place
> Chance
> Oriental Avenue
> Ventnor Avenue
> Electric Company
> Tennessee Avenue
> Indiana Avenue
> North Carolina Avenue
> Go
> Atlantic Avenue
> Go
> Electric Company
> North Carolina Avenue
> Tennessee Avenue
> Luxury Tax
> Electric Company
> Kentucky Avenue
> Illinois Avenue
> Short Line
> St. Charles Place
> Community Chest
> Oriental Avenue
> Marvin Gardens
> Pensilvania Avenue
> Luxury Tax
> Electric Company
> Marvin Gardens
> Electric Company
> North Carolina Avenue
> Tennessee Avenue
> Indiana Avenue
> North Carolina Avenue
> Go
> Marvin Gardens
> Electric Company
> Indiana Avenue
> North Carolina Avenue
> Luxury Tax
> Income Tax
> Free Parking
> Electric Company
> Pensilvania Railroad
> Luxury Tax
> Electric Company
> Atlantic Avenue
> Short Line
> Electric Company
> B&O Railroad
> Electric Company
> Tennessee Avenue
> Oriental Avenue
> Marvin Gardens
> Electric Company
> Atlantic Avenue
> Luxury Tax
> Oriental Avenue
> Virgina Avenue
> Indiana Avenue
> North Carolina Avenue
> Go
> Water Works
> Income Tax
> Free Parking
> Electric Company
> ```

Comment: That game exists in europe. With different labels, of course.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, I'll edit that statement.

Comment: Do you read the dice top to bottom (each column is a line of the solution) or left to right (we have to guess at the line breaks)? If you read them vertically, then you would have to go to jail after rolling three doubles in a row.

Comment: @EngineerToast Left to right. And yes, we have to guess the line breaks as well as the spaces between words.

Answer (score 19):

> "monopolising"
> "dog-tired"
> "iron-willed"
> "wheelbarrow-loads"
> "thimble"
> "hat"
> Monopoly, a game of taxes and work ethic, and one with game pieces including red dice, a dog, an iron, a wheelbarrow, a thimble and a hat!
>
>
> Imogen states that she and Ronnie live in America, not Europe, so we know we have to use the American version of the Monopoly board, not the European one (or UK one, or Canadian one, or Star Wars one or...)
>
> Starting at Go and moving around the board according to the dice pairs (including the "extra turns" on doubles, which effectively just skips that space), we can take the first letter of each property we land on to make this stanza:
>
>
> IMOGEN IN LOVING BLISS
> COVETING A GENTLE KISS
> COMPLEMENTING ME IN LIFE
> PLEASE BE TO ME A LOVING WIFE
>
> Something big for the weekend indeed!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @ArbitraryKangaroo, that actually gave me the hint I needed to get the message!